# How to change Razorpay.js file to make my code work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I'm integrating Razorpay to process payments and I'm using the node-JS sdk.

See this link for reference: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/blob/master/examples/index.js.

Now, I'm trying to capture a payment that has been authorized using my firebase cloud functions. Refer to line 32 in the link that I've shared above.

Let me show you the cloud function I've written:

```
exports.CapturePayment = functions.database.ref('payment_id').onWrite((event) => {

  const payment_id = event.data.val();

  // Capture a particular payment
rzp.payments.capture(payment_id, 1000).then((data) => {
  event.data.ref.child('status').set("paid");
  // success
}).catch((error) => {
  // error
});

});
```

When I run it, I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/abKoe.jpg

I have attached screenshots of both my razorpay.js file and index.js file. Can someone point out my mistake and help me make it work?

razorpay.js: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbEYl.jpg
index.js: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEEh3.jpg

PS: I'm very new to Node.JS so I think it could be a syntax error.

Update 1:
I changed the environment variable declaration to `

```
let rzp = new Razorpay({
  key_id: process.env.KEY_ID || "rzp_test_T1334114312"  , // your `KEY_ID`
  key_secret: process.env.KEY_SECRET || "K7W234fdsCt4dE12341" // your `KEY_SECRET`
})`
```

and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please do not post you key and secret publicly, they are confidential, anyone can gain access to your account with those credentials.

Comment: Never post screen-shots if they can be avoided.  It is far better to cut-and-paste the error message into your post itself.

Comment: The key and secret that I posted are modified/fake. Sorry for not posting screenshots, will make sure I do that next time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise RazorPay SDK with the `key_id` and `key_secret`. You can either set the environment variable or directly pass the values as shown below.

`process.env` are environment variables, they need to configured. You do not just replace them in the code (which I saw in the screenshot).

```
let rzp = new Razorpay({
  key_id: process.env.KEY_ID || "<your actual key id>", 
  key_secret: process.env.KEY_SECRET || "<your actual key secret>" 
})
```

That is why its throwing an error that the key_id is missing.

Comment: I made the change and I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: let rzp = new Razorpay({
  key_id: process.env.KEY_ID || "rzp_test_T1334114312" , // your `KEY_ID`
  key_secret: process.env.KEY_SECRET || "K7W234fdsCt4dE12341" // your `KEY_SECRET`
})

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since the error is thrown by a very basic string check. Did you modify any of the SDK files?

Comment: No, I did not! Does anything need to be changed in the razorpay.js file where the error is being thrown? In 'function Razorpay()' specifically?

Comment: All I did was first type 'npm i install' in the command line. Then navigated to the appropriate folder and typed npm install. That's it! Didn't touch anything inside!

Comment: No, SDK files should not be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171424/discussion-between-arjun-ram-and-arjun-komath).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a simple syntax error while declaring the environment variables. I just had to declare it as follows:

process.env.KEY_ID = 'randomstring1';
process.env.KEY_SECRET = 'randomstring2';

and it works!